# Page can't render when running from Home Screen on iPad

Tags: ipad, asp.net-mvc-2, safari, mobile-safari, homescreen

I have a web app that runs on an iPad with no problem. However, in Safari, when I'm on the page and choose "Add to Home Screen" then click the icon to open the page, I get the following error:

> This page contains the following errors:
>
> error on line 1 at column 2: StartTag: invalid element name
>
> Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

It's blank after the error since it is occurring on line 1.

Why would it work when running it within the browser but not when running it from the home screen? I was under the assumption that it still used the Safari engine either way.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might actually be a generic IIS / .NET error rather than a Safari rendering error. Maybe you can capture the User-agent string from fullscreen iPad Safari and see if it differs from regular Safari. From there you could spoof it into Firefox / Chrome and see what happens next.